# Silverlight textbox with custom controls before text

Tags: silverlight, facebook, textbox

How to implement textbox similar to facebook textbox in privacy settings where you can add to textbox custom controls:

[image: Facebook privacy settings: custom]

One of the way that i came to is to create wrappanel where last item will be textbox.
Are there any other ways?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's the only thing that comes to my mind... just have a stackpanel (wrappanel) and add items from left to right where the last one is the actual textbox...place everything in a nice canvas add some border and set the margins of the textbox to 0 so that it will fill up all the space if there is no other control in it...

it looks like it's not that big of a problem:)